# Setting up sourcepath for deploy task on azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

This is my first pipeline so i am sure i am missing something really simple.

I create and run successfully a azure pipeline.
Now i want to create a release and transfer it to my ftp server, so i created a release, connected it to the build artifact and then add a stage.

On the stage i add a ftp task to upload the release.
The problem is what i should set on the root field. I try many things but none works. 
I set the value using the browsing window but points to an invalid location. I try many variations with no success.

This is the yml:

```
steps:
- task: FtpUpload@2
  displayName: 'FTP Upload: /'
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: inputs
    serverUrl: '*****'
    username: ****
    password: '*****'
    rootDirectory: /
    remoteDirectory: '/azure/$(Build.BuildId)/'
```

This is the log:

> 2019-11-22T15:14:43.8429924Z ##[section]Starting: FTP Upload:
>   $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_AzureTP-ASP.NET Core (.NET
>   Framework)-CI 2019-11-22T15:14:44.0673529Z
>   ============================================================================== 2019-11-22T15:14:44.0673684Z Task         : FTP upload
>   2019-11-22T15:14:44.0673747Z Description  : Upload files using FTP
>   2019-11-22T15:14:44.0673783Z Version      : 2.157.0
>   2019-11-22T15:14:44.0673817Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
>   2019-11-22T15:14:44.0673852Z Help         :
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload
>   2019-11-22T15:14:44.0673903Z
>   ============================================================================== 2019-11-22T15:14:44.6355305Z ##[error]Error: ENOENT: no such file or
>   directory, stat 'D:\a\r1\a_AzureTP-ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)-CI'

ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\a\r1\a\$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'

Comment: Did you get a chance to try out below answer? Please let me know how did it go? We can discuss it and work out a better solution together.

Comment: I solved before by using navigation on Root folder field. The filed ended with the value 
´$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_AzureTP-ASP.NET Core-CI/drop/ConsoleApp.zip.´

Comment: But then i try your solution too. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root Directory should be point to the folder where the build artifacts resides. In the release pipeline,the build artifacts usually is downloaded in folder `C:\agent\_work\r1\a`which is referenced by `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) or $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)`. You can check the release variables [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch)

Below yaml is for example. Hope it helps

`steps:
- task: FtpUpload@2
  displayName: 'FTP Upload: /'
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: inputs
    serverUrl: '*****'
    username: ****
    password: '*****'
    rootDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    filePatterns: '**' 
    remoteDirectory: '/azure/$(Build.BuildId)/'`

Answer (score 0):

Build variables don't exist in the context of a release. You're trying to use build variables. Refer to the "[predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)" documentation, to which a link is provided on the variables tab of your release.

Comment: Looks like it should be Build.BinariesDirectory variable, but setting field with $(Build.BinariesDirectory) returns the error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\($Build.BinariesDirectory)\'. Seams to be a syntax error i follow the example.

Comment: @MiguelSlv That's a **build** variable. As my answer stated, **build variables are not present in releases**. Please refer to the documentation I provided in order to find **release** variables.